# wdio disableWebdriverStepsReporting: false setting

Tags: webdriver-io, allure

I have some troubles with "disableWebdriverStepsReporting: false" from webdriver.io allure reporting https://webdriver.io/docs/allure-reporter/. Does it really working?

Would like to log all the steps wdio is performing, but it doesnt matter if the setting is true or false, nothing is reported to generated allure report and body is empty.

Custom steps are working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Cucumber framework?

my allure settings in `wdio.conf.ts` are

```
"allure",
                {
                    outputDir: "allure-results",
                    useCucumberStepReporter: true,
                    disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
                    disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
                },
```

note the `useCucumberStepReporter: true`

Comment: Hi, no, we are not using cucumber. Just normal webdriver.io with mocha framework